# Using construct instead of object manager

Tags: magento2, construct

I'm running into an error while converting below code that uses object manager to injecting within construct instead.

In this example i have this code:

```
$objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId());
```

So I want to use the `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable` within the construct so assumed i would add to my current construct like below:

```
//1. Add variable
protected $catalogProductTypeConfigurable;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
//2. Add Class here next to variable defined before construct      
   \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable $catalogProductTypeConfigurable,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->_catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
    $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
    //3. Also add here so this class is passed to our variable
    $this->catalogProductTypeConfigurable = $catalogProductTypeConfigurable;
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $data
    );
}
```

So steps 1 sets variable, 2 takes class and passes to construct, and 3 sets this to a local variable. This then allow me to use getParentsIdsByChild function from `$this->catalogProductTypeConfigurable`.

**e.g.**

```
$this->catalogProductTypeConfigurable->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId());
```

This however throws following error:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 5 passed to Vendor\\Module\\Block\\CustomBlock::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\\ConfigurableProduct\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Product\\Type\\Configurable, array given
```

I would like any advice on how to do this correctly.

Comment: Have you cleared 'var/generation'? The error looks like your new constructor argument isn't being passed, which is often caused by the generated code not yet being updated.

Comment: I am using developer mode is this still necessary? Ok yeah that seems to have fixed it however

Comment: Yes. The dev docs contain more detail about which caches should be cleared and when during development http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/php/php_clear-dirs.html

Comment: Awesome thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just to tie this question up the main issue i was facing was clearing var/generation as suggested in comment my Pmclain.

> Example use of object manager

```
$objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId());
```

This states that we require the use of `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable`  class to use the getParentIdsByChild method

Construct should be used instead of object manager directly however so follow below steps:

> 1. Define Variable before construct:

```
protected $catalogProductTypeConfigurable;
```

> 2. Pass class to construct and set to our variable defined in step 1:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
    //a. Add Class here followed by variable defined in step 1   
   \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable $catalogProductTypeConfigurable,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->_catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
    $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
    //b. Also add here so this class is passed to our variable
    $this->catalogProductTypeConfigurable = $catalogProductTypeConfigurable;
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $data
    );
}
```

So the class is passed through construct method and set to `$this->catalogProductTypeConfigurable`

> 3. Using the method

This then allows the use of getParentIdsByChild method by using `$this->catalogProductTypeConfigurable`

**e.g.**

```
$this->catalogProductTypeConfigurable->getParentIdsByChild('1');
```

> 4. Clear Generation folder

Changing of classes requires var/generation to be cleared otherwise you may run into issue stated in my question. Delete this by running below from your Magento root directory.

```
rm -rf var/generation/*
```

Credit to step 4 goes to Pmclain for helping me in comments.